# How to create plugin for iOS framework using React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Iam new to react native, how can I create plugin in react-native.
I have my own Embedded framework,Where I want to include this framework in plugin.Any idea

Please any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of detailed tutorials already available, I believe I used this one in the past on medium: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-native-native-modules-with-swift-6768ea03b3f

The React Native doc also gives a helpful tutorial: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios

And if it's for a Native UI Component follow that tutorial with this one: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-ios

Hope it helps, otherwise a google search for "react native ios bridge tutorial" gives you many more. Good luck!